# How extract information from a json retrieved from an API with foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I have a code to get the value of "Kills" from an API (if it got just 1 "Kills" in the result) , but what i really need its get all values for each "Kills" in the API (using `foreach()`) and save the addition of those values in `$Kills`.

Code :

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('API LINK HERE);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['matches'][0]['participants'][0]['stats']['kills'];
?>
```

API (with more than just 1 "Kills"):

```
{
"matches": [{
    "matchId": 2026975440,
    "region": "EUW",
    "platformId": "EUW1",
    "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
    "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "matchCreation": 1427061117215,
    "matchDuration": 1710,
    "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    "mapId": 11,
    "season": "SEASON2015",
    "matchVersion": "5.5.0.273",
    "participants": [{
        "teamId": 100,
        "spell1Id": 14,
        "spell2Id": 4,
        "championId": 91,
        "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "UNRANKED",
        "timeline": {
            "creepsPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 3.8,
                "tenToTwenty": 2.9000000000000004
            },
            "xpPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 338.79999999999995,
                "tenToTwenty": 306.6
            },
            "goldPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 165.5,
                "tenToTwenty": 257.2
            },
            "csDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": -2.6000000000000005,
                "tenToTwenty": -1.4999999999999998
            },
            "xpDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": -161.10000000000005,
                "tenToTwenty": -201.1
            },
            "damageTakenPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 451.5,
                "tenToTwenty": 774.2
            },
            "damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 115.5,
                "tenToTwenty": 148.89999999999998
            },
            "role": "SOLO",
            "lane": "MIDDLE"
        },
        "masteries": [{
            "masteryId": 4113,
            "rank": 4
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4114,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4122,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4124,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4132,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4134,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4142,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4144,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4152,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4162,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4211,
            "rank": 2
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4213,
            "rank": 2
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4221,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4222,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4232,
            "rank": 1
        }],
        "stats": {
            "winner": false,
            "champLevel": 13,
            "item0": 3142,
            "item1": 3074,
            "item2": 2003,
            "item3": 3270,
            "item4": 0,
            "item5": 0,
            "item6": 3340,
            "kills": 6,
            "doubleKills": 1,
            "tripleKills": 0,
            "quadraKills": 0,
            "pentaKills": 0,
            "unrealKills": 0,
            "largestKillingSpree": 2,
            "deaths": 11,
            "assists": 6,
            "totalDamageDealt": 63231,
            "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 12035,
            "totalDamageTaken": 22391,
            "largestCriticalStrike": 330,
            "totalHeal": 837,
            "minionsKilled": 94,
            "neutralMinionsKilled": 3,
            "neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle": 3,
            "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle": 0,
            "goldEarned": 8269,
            "goldSpent": 7555,
            "combatPlayerScore": 0,
            "objectivePlayerScore": 0,
            "totalPlayerScore": 0,
            "totalScoreRank": 0,
            "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 0,
            "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 11631,
            "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 404,
            "visionWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "sightWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "magicDamageDealt": 0,
            "physicalDamageDealt": 62827,
            "trueDamageDealt": 404,
            "magicDamageTaken": 4304,
            "physicalDamageTaken": 17787,
            "trueDamageTaken": 299,
            "firstBloodKill": false,
            "firstBloodAssist": false,
            "firstTowerKill": false,
            "firstTowerAssist": false,
            "firstInhibitorKill": false,
            "firstInhibitorAssist": false,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "towerKills": 0,
            "wardsPlaced": 5,
            "wardsKilled": 0,
            "largestMultiKill": 2,
            "killingSprees": 1,
            "totalUnitsHealed": 1,
            "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt": 542
        },
        "participantId": 0,
        "runes": [{
            "runeId": 5245,
            "rank": 9
        }, {
            "runeId": 5287,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "runeId": 5296,
            "rank": 6
        }, {
            "runeId": 5317,
            "rank": 9
        }, {
            "runeId": 5335,
            "rank": 3
        }]
    }],
    "participantIdentities": [{
        "participantId": 0,
        "player": {
            "summonerId": 66448116,
            "summonerName": "name",
            "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/217403527",
            "profileIcon": 590
        }
    }]
}, {
    "matchId": 2034475179,
    "region": "EUW",
    "platformId": "EUW1",
    "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
    "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "matchCreation": 1427400448291,
    "matchDuration": 2225,
    "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
    "mapId": 11,
    "season": "SEASON2015",
    "matchVersion": "5.6.0.190",
    "participants": [{
        "teamId": 100,
        "spell1Id": 3,
        "spell2Id": 4,
        "championId": 53,
        "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "UNRANKED",
        "timeline": {
            "creepsPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 0.9,
                "tenToTwenty": 0.9,
                "twentyToThirty": 0.6,
                "thirtyToEnd": 1.2
            },
            "xpPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 253.60000000000002,
                "tenToTwenty": 237.8,
                "twentyToThirty": 477.29999999999995,
                "thirtyToEnd": 448.4
            },
            "goldPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 128.2,
                "tenToTwenty": 169.6,
                "twentyToThirty": 310.9,
                "thirtyToEnd": 211.2
            },
            "csDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": -0.8,
                "tenToTwenty": -0.5499999999999998,
                "twentyToThirty": -1.2499999999999998,
                "thirtyToEnd": -0.30000000000000027
            },
            "xpDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": -12.299999999999983,
                "tenToTwenty": -127.04999999999998,
                "twentyToThirty": 120.09999999999997,
                "thirtyToEnd": -491.9
            },
            "damageTakenPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 187.2,
                "tenToTwenty": 644.0999999999999,
                "twentyToThirty": 1015.2,
                "thirtyToEnd": 2076.2
            },
            "damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas": {
                "zeroToTen": 9.149999999999963,
                "tenToTwenty": 32.49999999999997,
                "twentyToThirty": 126.24999999999991,
                "thirtyToEnd": 762.9000000000001
            },
            "role": "DUO_SUPPORT",
            "lane": "BOTTOM"
        },
        "masteries": [{
            "masteryId": 4211,
            "rank": 2
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4213,
            "rank": 2
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4221,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4222,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4232,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4233,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4234,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4244,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4312,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4313,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4322,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4324,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4331,
            "rank": 3
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4334,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4341,
            "rank": 1
        }, {
            "masteryId": 4342,
            "rank": 1
        }],
        "stats": {
            "winner": false,
            "champLevel": 15,
            "item0": 2049,
            "item1": 3401,
            "item2": 3270,
            "item3": 2010,
            "item4": 3110,
            "item5": 3082,
            "item6": 3340,
            "kills": 1,
            "doubleKills": 0,
            "tripleKills": 0,
            "quadraKills": 0,
            "pentaKills": 0,
            "unrealKills": 0,
            "largestKillingSpree": 0,
            "deaths": 11,
            "assists": 10,
            "totalDamageDealt": 31311,
            "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 9198,
            "totalDamageTaken": 31747,
            "largestCriticalStrike": 0,
            "totalHeal": 3600,
            "minionsKilled": 36,
            "neutralMinionsKilled": 0,
            "neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle": 0,
            "neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle": 0,
            "goldEarned": 8264,
            "goldSpent": 8055,
            "combatPlayerScore": 0,
            "objectivePlayerScore": 0,
            "totalPlayerScore": 0,
            "totalScoreRank": 0,
            "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 7159,
            "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 2038,
            "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 0,
            "visionWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "sightWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
            "magicDamageDealt": 22000,
            "physicalDamageDealt": 5572,
            "trueDamageDealt": 3737,
            "magicDamageTaken": 15037,
            "physicalDamageTaken": 16608,
            "trueDamageTaken": 102,
            "firstBloodKill": false,
            "firstBloodAssist": false,
            "firstTowerKill": false,
            "firstTowerAssist": false,
            "firstInhibitorKill": false,
            "firstInhibitorAssist": false,
            "inhibitorKills": 0,
            "towerKills": 0,
            "wardsPlaced": 28,
            "wardsKilled": 1,
            "largestMultiKill": 1,
            "killingSprees": 0,
            "totalUnitsHealed": 4,
            "totalTimeCrowdControlDealt": 445
        },
        "participantId": 0,
        "runes": [{
            "runeId": 5273,
            "rank": 9
        }, {
            "runeId": 5289,
            "rank": 9
        }, {
            "runeId": 5317,
            "rank": 9
        }, {
            "runeId": 5357,
            "rank": 3
        }]
    }],
    "participantIdentities": [{
        "participantId": 0,
        "player": {
            "summonerId": 66388144,
            "summonerName": "name",
            "matchHistoryUri": "/v1/stats/player_history/EUW1/214403527",
            "profileIcon": 690
        }
    }]
}]
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you can do that like this :

```
foreach($data['matches'] as $matches){
    $kills += $matches['participants'][0]['stats']['kills'];
}
```

Comment: I got the value 67 when i try `echo $kills;` , but the true value is 7 (6+1) soo something is wrong.

Comment: You put your 'echo' in the loop. Please, leave your echo line from the foreach. You will have '7'. `foreach($data['matches'] as $matches){
    $kills += $matches['participants'][0]['stats']['kills'];
}
echo $kills;`